# Impelement a generic parser class

Tags: java, parsing, generics, functional-programming, java-8

I wanna to write a generic excel parser class. But there is a problem with passing functions to it.

A parser read excel rows and create an object from each rows. By a systemic view, it get an excel file, a class and a mapping between each column and an object field (its setter function) and generate a list of objects.

If we create a `Parser` for each pojos (`StudentParser` for `Student` pojo and `SchoolParser` for `School`), there is a lot of duplicates in these parsers. So, Implementation of a generic `Parser` class is required, but I have no idea for passing setter methods to the class. We need something like this:

```
private Map<Integer, java.util.function.Consumer> mapColumnIndexToSetter = new HashMap<>();
mapColumnIndexToSetter .put(3, Student::setName);
```

But `Student::setName` gets an error:

```
Error:(30, 41) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String`
```

I know the above code does can not meet my requirements. But It gives some idea about what is the requirements.

I have two questions on implementation of this generic `Parser` class in java 8:

1. How can I pass class and setter methods to parser class?
2. How to new a generic class (call its constructor) and set its field using the mentioned setter?

Comment: I'm curious on how do you use the `Function` after you stored inside the `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method like `Student.setName(String)` requires *two* arguments, the `Student` instance to invoke the method on and the `String` to be passed. Therefore, an appropriate functional interface would be `BiConsumer<Student,String>`.

By the way, the columns of an excel table are rarely that sparse that they justify the use of a *`HashMap`* from index to function. A `List` having a function for each column is straight-forward.

To instantiate the type, you may use a `Supplier`.

Putting it together, such a class may look like

```
public class Parser<T> {
    public static final BiConsumer<Object,Object> IGNORE = (x,y) -> {};

    private final Supplier<? extends T> instantiator;
    private final List<BiConsumer<? super T, ? super String>> setters;

    public Parser(Supplier<? extends T> instantiator,
                  List<BiConsumer<? super T, ? super String>> setters) {
        this.instantiator = Objects.requireNonNull(instantiator);
        this.setters = new ArrayList<>(setters);
        if(this.setters.contains(null)) throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    public Parser(Supplier<? extends T> instantiator,
                  BiConsumer<? super T, ? super String>... setters) {
        this(instantiator, Arrays.asList(setters));
    }

    // Replace the two-dimensional string array with actual xls parsing...
    public List<T> parse(String[][] data) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(data.length);
        for(String[] row: data) {
            T instance = instantiator.get();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < row.length; ix++)
                setters.get(ix).accept(instance, row[ix]);
            result.add(instance);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, to instantiate `Student`s only using the 3rd column to initialize their names, you can use

```
Parser<Student> parser = new Parser<>(Student::new,
                                      Parser.IGNORE, Parser.IGNORE, Student::setName);
List<Student> list = parser.parse(new String[][] {
                                      {null,         null,          "Moe" },
                                      {null,         null,          "Larry" },
                                      {null,         null,          "Curly" },
});
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I implement this but when I instantiate `Parser` in a non-static method, it gets the following error on `Student::setName`: `java: invalid method reference
  non-static method setName() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Are you sure about the “non-static method” when the error message says “from a static context”? Check in which regard your code differs from [this successfully running code](https://ideone.com/AgHj26)…

Comment: Yeah I try it twice, in a static context (Main) and also non-static context (A public non-static class).

Comment: Sometimes, the compiler likes to give spurious errors hiding the actual problem. Check that all used types are correctly imported and that you didn’t forget a `<>`, etc. And compare with the link I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: You are right, It is not a real error. I found the real error: you write `? super String` as parameter of BiConsumer. but we have other data type fields like Integer, Date and Long. I use `? super Object` instead. but compiler cannot convert it: `java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.String`. How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no way to treat arbitrarily typed functions uniformly. You can make the `Parser` accept arbitrary functions using `BiConsumer<? super T, ?>`, but you can’t invoke its `accept` method without an unchecked operation (e.g. `((BiConsumer)c).accept(anObject,aValue)`, as there is no way to prove at compile time that the type of the XLS cell matches the parameter type of the setter. You can only try to spot errors earlier by encapsulating column setups in a dedicated class, i.e. `Column<V>` holding the expected type (`Class<V>`) and setter (`BiConsumer<? super T, ? super V>`).

Answer (score 2):

The `Function` you are passing is not compatible with the `Map's` declaration.

At the `Map` declaration you missed to specify generic type arguments for `Function`, so those will be inferred as follows:

```
Function<Object, Object>
```

On the other hand you are passing:

```
// I guess getName() is returning a String
Function<Student, String> function = Student::getName;
```

Now generic type arguments in such references have to match exactly unless specified otherwise, which would look like:

```
Function<? extends Object, ? extends Object>
```

And as long as you are fine with getting `Object` from the `Function` call, `extends Object` is obviously pointless, so it can be reduced to:

```
Function<?, ?>
```

But you might as well add a generic restriction here, such as:

```
Function<?, ? extends Serializable>
```

Comment: Pardon, it is the error of `setName(String name)` not `getName()`. You answer which of my two questions?

Comment: Did he edit the question? The `Map`is `Integer` to `Consumer`, not `Function`.

Comment: Yeah, I edit the text: `getName()` --> `setName` and `Function` to --> `Consumer` (because setter does not have any output). but this changes not affect my main questions